# Scipy semilogx: How to set label on each lines

Tags: python, matplotlib, scipy

I refer to 
[image: plot] 
command, I tried:

```
plt.figure()
plt.semilogx(hs_001u_w,hs_001u_mag,color="red",label="u")
plt.semilogx(hs_01u_w,hs_01u_mag,color="blue",label="u1")
plt.grid()
plt.show()
```

But result seems `label="u"` does not work:
[image: p]
`semilogx`'s official docs does not mention how to add label for each lines,

maybe has but I have not found.

Does anyone knows?

Comment: Don't forget to put `plt.legend()` in the code.

Comment: @Péter Leéh : Thanks! I success. Please post it to answer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I commented, you must call `plt.legend()` somewhere in the code, before `plt.show()` to acutally show the labels.